# What's the proper verb to describe quantitative research?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What would be the proper verb for an action that measures with numbers something that used to be measured qualitatively? I mean the verb for converting quality to quantity.

For example:

> Fornel (the verb that I search for)s customer satisfaction for the
>   first time.

I can say that he used a quantitative approach or something like this, but I would like to somehow express that he did it for the first time in a quantitative manner.
A verb like *digitize* for example defines making digits from a picture or videos, so I think in English there should be a verb that fits my question.

Comment: I think "quantify" would fit. You may also find the answers to the following question helpful: [Is there a synonym for “numerifying”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285467/is-there-a-synonym-for-numerifying)

Comment: "Measuring KPIs (*Key Performance indicators*), Fornel *monitors* customer satisfaction for the first time".

Comment: @sumelic Big Kiss and warm hug dear. It perfectly fit with my statement.

Comment: @ Graffito, Thanks for your response but i couldn't catch your point for using the verb monitor. I think it means Control, Observe or something like this. But I wanted to find a verb which defines "to express in quantitative terms, or as a numerical equivalent"

Comment: When you say *"measures with numbers something that used to be measured qualitatively"*, do you mean something objective like temperature, something semi-subjective like pain, or something totally subjective like enjoyment? I mean strictly, we can't "quantify" enjoyment, but we can quantify more quantifiable things.

Comment: @haji Hey have you got any comment on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how subjective/objective and how easy/hard/impossible the quantity is to quantify, you could use: ***measured, quantified, characterized, described, analyzed, studied, performed a [quantitative] study of, investigated, examined...***

Also possibly ***codified, formalized, systematized, canonicalized, defined/devised a quantitative scale/units for...***

Like I commented, it depends on whether you're talking about e.g. measuring temperatures, or self-reported level of perceived pain in patients, or customer satisfaction, or brand sentiment on social media. There is no one single best term. Even for customer satisfaction, there are different ways to measure it and different behaviors or attitudes to quantify.

Answer (score 1):

Calculates, quantifies, measures, appraises, assays (or assesses), and gauges are all verbs that can mean 'quantifies' in the case of

> Fornel _______s customer satisfaction for the first time.